# How to isolate specific words from a string in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I've looked into other similar posts, and all the ones I've seen are strings with spaces. How about splitting strings that do not contain any spaces? I know how to separate the numbers, but I'm not sure about splitting specific words like Delta, Sigma, Gamma, and Alpha.

```
// the one below is the string to be separated
//11020#Delta-99998#Sigma-45201#Gamma-69420#Gamma-90967#Alpha-

int[] numbers = new int[numberOnly.length()];
for(int i =0; i<numberOnly.length();i++) {
    numbers[i] = numberOnly.charAt(i)-'0';
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to separate by capital letters?

Comment: @MattDog_222Overwatch I'm trying to separate the letters out in general, possibly into an array if that works.

Comment: "Separate the letters" is fairly vague. `String#toCharArray()` exists and returns a `char[]`, but I'm not sure if that's what you'd want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Or Operator**

```
class Regx{
    public static void main(String ...$){
        String s = "11020#Delta-99998#Sigma-45201#Gamma-69420#Gamma-90967#Alpha-";
        var out = System.out;
        String arr[] = s.split("Delta|Sigma|Gamma|Alpha");
        for(var a : arr)
            out.println(a);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
$ java Regx 
11020#
-99998#
-45201#
-69420#
-90967#
-
```

If you want to separate `#` and `-` as well :

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
class Regx{
    public static void main(String ...$){
        String s = "11020#Delta-99998#Sigma-45201#Gamma-69420#Gamma-90967#Alpha-";
        var out = System.out;
        var arr = Stream.of(s.split("Delta|Sigma|Gamma|Alpha|#|-")).filter(str->str.length() !=0).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(var a : arr)
            out.println(a);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
$ javac Regx.java && java Regx
11020
99998
45201
69420
90967
```